# ORA-00918: column ambiguous defined when joining subquery table

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

The following code works:

```
SELECT b.AAZ002
FROM 
AE02 b
INNER JOIN t_aa10 aa10 
    ON (aa10.AAA100 = 'AA5515' AND  b.AA5515 = aa10.AAA102)
```

But when I change b to a subquery table, it reports ambigious column error:

```
SELECT b.AAZ002 
FROM 
(
    select count(1) count1, a.BAZ379 , max(a.AB0111) AB0111, max(a.AA5515) AA5515, max(a.AAE011) AAE011
    , max(a.AAE035) AAE035, max(a.AAE036) AAE036, max(a.AAE012) AAE012, max(a.AAE012) AAE012
    , max(a.ZA0100) ZA0100
    from AE02 a
    where a.BAE028 = '1'
    group by a.BAZ379 
) b
INNER JOIN t_aa10 aa10 
    ON (aa10.AAA100 = 'AA5515' AND  b.AA5515 = aa10.AAA102)
```

Dbeaver reported these 3 errors:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
SQL Error [918] [42000]: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
    Script-8.sql    /General/Scripts    Unknown Database Script Problem
SQL Error [933] [42000]: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
    Script-8.sql    /General/Scripts    Unknown Database Script Problem
SQL Error [979] [42000]: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
    Script-8.sql    /General/Scripts    Unknown Database Script Problem
```

I have prefix on every column, it should not be ambiguous. What could be the cause?

Comment: The subquery have duplicated column  `AAE012`

Comment: And `b.AAZ002` is missing from the sub query.

Comment: In case you observe such issues in future and don't find the problem when just having a look on the whole query, remove one after one the selected columns from the sub query to find that one which causes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected the sql after astentx and YoYo pointed out errors. Here is the corrected sql:

```
SELECT b.AAZ002 
FROM 
(
    select count(1) count1, a.BAZ379 , max(a.AB0111) AB0111, max(a.AA5515) AA5515, max(a.AAE011) AAE011
    , max(a.AAE035) AAE035, max(a.AAE036) AAE036, max(a.AAE012) AAE012, max(AAZ002) AAZ002
    , max(a.ZA0100) ZA0100
    from AE02 a
    where a.BAE028 = '1'
    group by a.BAZ379 
) b
INNER JOIN t_aa10 aa10 
    ON (aa10.AAA100 = 'AA5515' AND  b.AA5515 = aa10.AAA102)
INNER JOIN AB01 ab 
    ON ab.ZA0100 = b.ZA0100
```